# Copy and paste a Row and delete certain cells

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to copy paste a row (A3:S3) to the next free row of my sheet.
This works fine with the following code. 
What I am now trying to do is to delete the cells C3-K3.

```
function copypastescript() {
var reference = 'Definitionstabelle!A2'; 
    var rng = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(reference);
    rng.setValue(rng.getValue()+1);
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet ();
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet ();
  var source = ss.getRange ("Definitionstabelle!A3:S3");
    var destSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Definitionstabelle");
    var values = source.getValues().filter(function(e) {return e.some(function(f) {return f})});
destSheet.getRange(destSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your 1st question was resolved. For your 2nd question, I added a modified script. Could you please confirm it? By the way, I think that you shouldn't post your comment as an answer. Please post it as a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Answer for Q1:

- You want to delete the cells "C3:K3" of the sheet of `Definitionstabelle` after the values of "A3:S3" are copied.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### Modified script:

Please add the following script after `destSheet.getRange(destSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);`.

```
ss.getRange ("Definitionstabelle!C3:K3").clearContent();
```

or

```
ss.getRange ("Definitionstabelle!C3:K3").clear();
```

#### References:

- [clearContent()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clearcontent)
- [clear()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clear())

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

### Answer for Q2:

> some code to copy K3 and paste it into J3 before deleting C3:I3 and K3

- You want to copy the value of "K3" to "J3" of the sheet "Definitionstabelle".
- You want to copy before the vaues of cells "C3:K3" are deleted.

**In your situation, should the copy from "K3" to "J3" be done before the copy of "A3:S3"?**

If my understanding is correct how about this modification?

Please put the following script before `ss.getRange ("Definitionstabelle!C3:K3").clear();`.

#### Modified script:

```
function copypastescript() {
  var reference = 'Definitionstabelle!A2'; 
  var rng = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(reference);
  rng.setValue(rng.getValue()+1);
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet ();
  var source = ss.getRange ("Definitionstabelle!A3:S3");
  var destSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Definitionstabelle");

  // Added
  destSheet.getRange("K3").copyTo(destSheet.getRange("J3"), {contentsOnly:true}); // or destSheet.getRange("K3").copyTo(destSheet.getRange("J3"))

  var values = source.getValues().filter(function(e) {return e.some(function(f) {return f})});
  destSheet.getRange(destSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);

  // Added
  ss.getRange ("Definitionstabelle!C3:K3").clearContent(); // or ss.getRange ("Definitionstabelle!C3:K3").clear()
}
```

#### Reference:

- [copyTo(destination, options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyTo(Range,Object))